# Modulus of continuity of integration

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, asymptotics, lebesgue-integral

A classic exercise is to show that integration is absolutely continuous. That is, for $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R}^n,\mu)$ and for all $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$ such that whenever the measure of $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ is less that $\delta$, I.e. $\mu(A)<\delta$, then one has $$\int_A |f|d\mu<\varepsilon$$

What I’m particularly interested in is if one can say anything about how fast the integral goes to zero with measure of the set. That is, can one say anything about the *rate of convergence* of the limit, $\lim_{\mu(A)\to0}\int_A|f|d\mu$?

If not, does anyone know of any conditions under which we can say something of the type?

Comment: You should be able to say something about some cases.  For instance, what happens when $n=1$ and $f(x) = x^{\varepsilon-1}$ for $x > 0$?  Contrast that to what happens when $f \in L^1 \cap L^\infty$.  Use those types of examples to refine your question.